# Whats the difference between DevOpenHelper and OpenHelper?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, greendao

Whats the difference between `DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper` and `DaoMaster.OpenHelper`?

Did not found any explanation when to use what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is greendao's generated `DaoMaster` class.

```
public static abstract class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public OpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory) {
        super(context, name, factory, SCHEMA_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        createAllTables(db, false);
    }
}

/** WARNING: Drops all table on Upgrade! Use only during development. */
public static class DevOpenHelper extends OpenHelper {
    public DevOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory) {
        super(context, name, factory);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        dropAllTables(db, true);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the comment:

> Drops all table on Upgrade! Use only during development.

I feel like it's pretty self-explanatory.

Also note, that `OpenHelper` is `abstract` class, and `DevOpenHelper` is an implementation of it.

Comment: Understand, thank you. will accept your answer in a couple of minutes when possible